# Is it correct to make a CSS class for this?

Tags: html, css

I have a many `h1 elements` that I want to remove the `margin` on.

Is it correct to make a `class` for this or would you target it indivually in the `CSS` such as

```css
#comments h1 { margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a class, you can reuse it for other elements as well:

```
.nomargin {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that this is a very poor use of classes. In fact, I'd say his original CSS is far better than this.

Comment: It is not a good idea to make a generic class for all elements that should have no margin in your current design. If you want to change the look of the site, you would have to change the html as well. But html should only describe the content semantically, and the same it is with classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the margin on **all** elements of a certain type, then you can use a generic element selector, for example

```
h1 { margin: 0; }
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/dDKHT/)

However, if you want to target **multiple** elements, but **not all** elements of a certain type, allocate the ones you want to target with a class such as `nomargin` and then use the following CSS

```
.nomargin { margin: 0; }
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/dDKHT/1/)

Comment: I disagree with you. There's nothing wrong with selecting a specific subset of `h1` elements by using a nested selector as he's done; there's nothing in his code that suggests a class is necessary. And you certainly shouldn't be creating a class that is as generic as `.nomargin`. A classname should be relevant to what the element is for, not what it looks like.

Comment: No there is nothing wrong with what he's done, but he did not provide us with enough info or code to fully understand which elements he wants to target. Therefore in my answer I addressed targeting multiple or all elements of a certain type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly good CSS to do that, assuming all the header tags are inside the element with `id='comments'`, and assuming that these are the only header tags that you want to act in this way.

If you have a more general need for elements that are to be styled this way, then maybe use a class, but since you already have a selector that gets all the elements you want to style, then use it; you shouldn't feel like you need to create a class just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 1):

I favor structural selectors over classes which denote specific styles. For example, what if you *do* want a margin when the site is viewed on a mobile device? Now your class name is wrong. An extreme example is naming classes things like "blue" or "15-pixel-text".

The structural selector can also be more intuitive when reading your stylesheets. You can infer where it will be applied rather than wondering to what elements the class name has been applied.

One consideration is that such selectors can become quite complex, and may perform worse than a class selector. As always, there is no hard and fast rule.

As a side note, you can make development/maintenance easier by using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). This doesn't address semantics concerns.